# FACEBOOK - integrating PHP SDK & JS SDK together - infinite refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an weird issue with facebook connect.
I've tried to run the basic example for JS & PHP SDKs.
While I connect to FB account via connect page, on my localhost it works well but in my web server it's getting refreshed non-stop.

The example is from here: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/examples
(with JS).

What may be the reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your app URL on your Facebook application settings. This has to match the URL of the script hosting your app. Otherwise it'll try to switch to the correct one.